# How to Melt a column into another melted column within Pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-melt

I have a file consisting of sales for different items.  I have a column of model predictions named `outputs` and which model produced those predictions named, `model`.  I need to take the current model's (that's in production) predictions in a column named 'FCAST_QTY`and make them part of the outputs column with the string "FCAST_QTY" being put into the`model `column.  So essentially, melting that column (`FCAST_QTY') into the columns `output` and `model` so the current production model is in the same columns and the multiple models that are in development.  This will make it easier to compare/contrast.  I'm not sure how to do this. Example data below.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
sales_dict = {'MO_YR': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00')},
 'ITEM_BASE': {0: '289461K',
  1: '289461K',
  2: '289461K',
  3: '289461K',
  4: '289461K',
  5: '289461K',
  6: '289461K',
  7: '289461K',
  8: '289461K',
  9: '289461K',
  10: '289461K',
  11: '289461K',
  12: '400520J',
  13: '400520J',
  14: '400520J'},
'eaches': {0: 2592,
  1: 3844,
  2: 759,
  3: 825,
  4: 663,
  5: 2025,
  6: 471,
  7: 1160,
  8: 5987,
  9: 679,
  10: 469,
  11: 907,
  12: 64,
  13: 48,
  14: 63},
'FCAST_QTY': {0: 2800.0,
  1: 5200.0,
  2: 550.0,
  3: 475.0,
  4: 575.0,
  5: 475.0,
  6: 650.0,
  7: 550.0,
  8: 7900.0,
  9: 1187.0,
  10: 1187.0,
  11: 1900.0,
  12: 51.0,
  13: 55.0,
  14: 59.0},
'log_eaches': {0: 7.860185057472165,
  1: 8.254268770090183,
  2: 6.63200177739563,
  3: 6.715383386334682,
  4: 6.496774990185863,
  5: 7.61332497954064,
  6: 6.154858094016418,
  7: 7.05617528410041,
  8: 8.697345730925353,
  9: 6.520621127558696,
  10: 6.15060276844628,
  11: 6.810142450115136,
  12: 4.158883083359672,
  13: 3.871201010907891,
  14: 4.143134726391533},
 'output': {0: 8.646015798513993,
  1: 8.378197900630752,
  2: 7.045235414873291,
  3: 5.117058321275769,
  4: 9.082928370640056,
  5: 5.225648643174155,
  6: 7.446383013291042,
  7: 6.307484284901181,
  8: 7.752673979530179,
  9: 9.02189934080111,
  10: 4.677594714421006,
  11: 7.218749101888444,
  12: 4.04018241973268,
  13: 3.940978322900716,
  14: 3.962359464699719},
 'model': {0: 'LR_output',
  1: 'LR_output',
  2: 'LR_output',
  3: 'LR_output',
  4: 'LR_output',
  5: 'LR_output',
  6: 'LR_output',
  7: 'LR_output',
  8: 'LR_output',
  9: 'LR_output',
  10: 'LR_output',
  11: 'LR_output',
  12: 'AR(12)',
  13: 'AR(12)',
  14: 'AR(12)'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales_dict)
```

**Expected Output Added:**

```
expected_dict = {'MO_YR': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
15: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'),
  19: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
  20: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  21: Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'),
  22: Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  23: Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),
  24: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  25: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  26: Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'),
  27: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  28: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  29: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00')},
 'ITEM_BASE': {0: '289461K',
  1: '289461K',
  2: '289461K',
  3: '289461K',
  4: '289461K',
  5: '289461K',
  6: '289461K',
  7: '289461K',
  8: '289461K',
  9: '289461K',
  10: '289461K',
  11: '289461K',
  12: '400520J',
  13: '400520J',
  14: '400520J',
15: '289461K',
  16: '289461K',
  17: '289461K',
  18: '289461K',
  19: '289461K',
  20: '289461K',
  21: '289461K',
  22: '289461K',
  23: '289461K',
  24: '289461K',
  25: '289461K',
  26: '289461K',
  27: '400520J',
  28: '400520J',
  29: '400520J'},
'eaches': {0: 2592,
  1: 3844,
  2: 759,
  3: 825,
  4: 663,
  5: 2025,
  6: 471,
  7: 1160,
  8: 5987,
  9: 679,
  10: 469,
  11: 907,
  12: 64,
  13: 48,
  14: 63,
15: 2592,
  16: 3844,
  17: 759,
  18: 825,
  19: 663,
  20: 2025,
  21: 471,
  22: 1160,
  23: 5987,
  24: 679,
  25: 469,
  26: 907,
  27: 64,
  28: 48,
  29: 63},
'log_eaches': {0: 7.860185057472165,
  1: 8.254268770090183,
  2: 6.63200177739563,
  3: 6.715383386334682,
  4: 6.496774990185863,
  5: 7.61332497954064,
  6: 6.154858094016418,
  7: 7.05617528410041,
  8: 8.697345730925353,
  9: 6.520621127558696,
  10: 6.15060276844628,
  11: 6.810142450115136,
  12: 4.158883083359672,
  13: 3.871201010907891,
  14: 4.143134726391533,
  15: 7.860185057472165,
  16: 8.254268770090183,
  17: 6.63200177739563,
  18: 6.715383386334682,
  19: 6.496774990185863,
  20: 7.61332497954064,
  21: 6.154858094016418,
  22: 7.05617528410041,
  23: 8.697345730925353,
  24: 6.520621127558696,
  25: 6.15060276844628,
  26: 6.810142450115136,
  27: 4.158883083359672,
  28: 3.871201010907891,
  29: 4.143134726391533,},
 'output': {0: 8.646015798513993,
  1: 8.378197900630752,
  2: 7.045235414873291,
  3: 5.117058321275769,
  4: 9.082928370640056,
  5: 5.225648643174155,
  6: 7.446383013291042,
  7: 6.307484284901181,
  8: 7.752673979530179,
  9: 9.02189934080111,
  10: 4.677594714421006,
  11: 7.218749101888444,
  12: 4.04018241973268,
  13: 3.940978322900716,
  14: 3.962359464699719,
  15: 2800.0,
  16: 5200.0,
  17: 550.0,
  18: 475.0,
  19: 575.0,
  20: 475.0,
  21: 650.0,
  22: 550.0,
  23: 7900.0,
  24: 1187.0,
  25: 1187.0,
  26: 1900.0,
  27: 51.0,
  28: 55.0,
  29: 59.0},
 'model': {0: 'LR_output',
  1: 'LR_output',
  2: 'LR_output',
  3: 'LR_output',
  4: 'LR_output',
  5: 'LR_output',
  6: 'LR_output',
  7: 'LR_output',
  8: 'LR_output',
  9: 'LR_output',
  10: 'LR_output',
  11: 'LR_output',
  12: 'AR(12)',
  13: 'AR(12)',
  14: 'AR(12)',
15:'FCAST_QTY',
16:'FCAST_QTY',
17:'FCAST_QTY',
18:'FCAST_QTY',
19:'FCAST_QTY',
20:'FCAST_QTY',
21:'FCAST_QTY',
22:'FCAST_QTY',
23:'FCAST_QTY',
24:'FCAST_QTY',
25:'FCAST_QTY',
26:'FCAST_QTY',
27:'FCAST_QTY',
28:'FCAST_QTY',
29:'FCAST_QTY'}}
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(expected_dict)
```

Comment: It's good if you can provide an expected output too. Thank you

Comment: Expected output added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new dataframe with your logic and append it to the original dataframe:

```py
fcast_qty = (df
             .drop(columns = ['output', 'model'])
             .rename(columns={"FCAST_QTY":"output"})
             .assign(model="FCAST_QTY")
            )

pd.concat([df.drop(columns='FCAST_QTY'), fcast_qty], ignore_index = True)
        MO_YR ITEM_BASE  eaches  log_eaches       output      model
0  2021-01-01   289461K    2592    7.860185     8.646016  LR_output
1  2021-02-01   289461K    3844    8.254269     8.378198  LR_output
2  2021-03-01   289461K     759    6.632002     7.045235  LR_output
3  2021-04-01   289461K     825    6.715383     5.117058  LR_output
4  2021-05-01   289461K     663    6.496775     9.082928  LR_output
5  2021-06-01   289461K    2025    7.613325     5.225649  LR_output
6  2021-07-01   289461K     471    6.154858     7.446383  LR_output
7  2021-08-01   289461K    1160    7.056175     6.307484  LR_output
8  2021-09-01   289461K    5987    8.697346     7.752674  LR_output
9  2021-10-01   289461K     679    6.520621     9.021899  LR_output
10 2021-11-01   289461K     469    6.150603     4.677595  LR_output
11 2021-12-01   289461K     907    6.810142     7.218749  LR_output
12 2021-01-01   400520J      64    4.158883     4.040182     AR(12)
13 2021-02-01   400520J      48    3.871201     3.940978     AR(12)
14 2021-03-01   400520J      63    4.143135     3.962359     AR(12)
15 2021-01-01   289461K    2592    7.860185  2800.000000  FCAST_QTY
16 2021-02-01   289461K    3844    8.254269  5200.000000  FCAST_QTY
17 2021-03-01   289461K     759    6.632002   550.000000  FCAST_QTY
18 2021-04-01   289461K     825    6.715383   475.000000  FCAST_QTY
19 2021-05-01   289461K     663    6.496775   575.000000  FCAST_QTY
20 2021-06-01   289461K    2025    7.613325   475.000000  FCAST_QTY
21 2021-07-01   289461K     471    6.154858   650.000000  FCAST_QTY
22 2021-08-01   289461K    1160    7.056175   550.000000  FCAST_QTY
23 2021-09-01   289461K    5987    8.697346  7900.000000  FCAST_QTY
24 2021-10-01   289461K     679    6.520621  1187.000000  FCAST_QTY
25 2021-11-01   289461K     469    6.150603  1187.000000  FCAST_QTY
26 2021-12-01   289461K     907    6.810142  1900.000000  FCAST_QTY
27 2021-01-01   400520J      64    4.158883    51.000000  FCAST_QTY
28 2021-02-01   400520J      48    3.871201    55.000000  FCAST_QTY
29 2021-03-01   400520J      63    4.143135    59.000000  FCAST_QTY
```